# How to calculate Percentage utilization of particular pod in kubernetes with metrics server?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to calculate the CPU and Memory Percentage of Resource utilization of an individual pod in Kubernetes. For that, I am using metrics server API

1. From the metrics server, I get the utilization from this command

kubectl top pods --all-namespaces

```
kube-system   coredns-5644d7b6d9-9whxx                   2m           6Mi
kube-system   coredns-5644d7b6d9-hzgjc                   2m           7Mi
kube-system   etcd-manhattan-master                      10m          53Mi
kube-system   kube-apiserver-manhattan-master            23m          257Mi
```

But I want the percentage utilization of individual pod Both CPU % and MEM%

From this output by top command it is not clear that from how much amount of cpu and memory it consumes the resultant amount?

I don't want to use Prometheus operator I saw one formula for it

```
sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!=""}[1m])) by (pod_name)
```

Can I calculate it with [MetricsServer](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) API?

I thought to calculate like this

**CPU%** = ((2+2+10+23)/ Total CPU MILLICORES)*100

**MEM%** = ((6+7+53+257)/AllocatableMemory)* 100

Please tell me if I right or wrong. Because I didn't see any standard formula for calculating pod utilization in Kubernetes documentation

Comment: you can install prometheus and grafana based helm chart provided by name of stable/prometheus

Comment: No i want to use metrics-server only

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `kubectl top pods` provides only a [quantity values](https://github.com/DirectXMan12/k8s-prometheus-adapter/blob/master/docs/walkthrough.md#quantity-values) and not a percentages.

[Here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/193#issuecomment-451309811) is a good explanation of how to interpret those values.

It is currently not possible to list pod resource usage in percentages with a `kubectl top` command.

You could still chose [Grafana with Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/visualization/grafana/) but it was already stated that you don't want to use it (however maybe another member of the community with similar problem would do so I am mentioning it here).

**EDIT:**

Your formulas are correct. They will calculate how much CPU/Mem is being consumed by all Pods relative to total CPU/Mem you got.

I hope it helps.

Comment: is that formula correct for CPU utilization = (sum of used cpu cores/1000*totalcpu core) *100

Comment: And for memory utilization = (sum of used Mib/Allocatable Memory) *100

Comment: You have to see it that way: 1 CPU = 1 core = 1000 milicores. So if you have 8 CPUs and your pods are using 400m that means they utilize 5% of your CPU. It's analogical for memory. So in short: yes, your formulas seems correct from mathematical point of view.

Comment: I knew that . I mean to say if I get used memory from kubectl top command. Can i calculate the CPU% and MEM% by above formula or not